# What extradimensional topology would explain looping forces?

Tags: magic, spacetime-dimensions, alien-geometry

In my magical world there are two contrary forces, or rather essences that flow in the two opposite directions of another dimension **perpendicular** to our own.

One is named aether and flows "up", the other is named nether and flows "down". When these two essences reach the "extremities" of this dimension, known to some as hell/heaven they loop down to the middle of this dimension which happens to intersects with the mortal realm.

---

Of course, this is just a way of visualising things, the dimension in reality **has no extremities** and is actually closed onto itself. However it isn't a simple loop as aether would just loop around and travel though "hell" until it reaches our world and vice versa for nether.

---

Instead I want each force to **only ever go through their asigned half** of the dimension.

So, **what, if any, dimensional topology would explain this phenomenon?**

Comment: I'm guessing "Because magic" isn't a valid response?

Comment: @Frostfyre Haha, no it most definitely isn't. I'm not asking how this dimension would come to be mind you, just what topology it would have to have to permit this.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the -1 and the vote to close, it might be a good idea however to tell me what you think is wrong with the question?

Comment: Angel I think the problem with your question is that there is no concrete or even logical answer to the question.  60 answers with 60 different ideas would all be equally valid as the question is currently written.  If you can better build out the framework and explain what would make an answer good that may help.

Comment: @James Unless there are 60 different topologies which would have these exact properties (something I find very unlikely since, topology is rather restrictive) then I don't see what you mean. I was attempt to edit the question.

Comment: If you really want a mathematically coherent topology, then you need to explain the constraints in a mathematically coherent way. How do I express "I want each force to only ever go through their assigned half of the dimension" in equations? The problem is that I don't understand what you are asking, so I am going to vote to close as such.

Comment: I *think* I understood it, and answered accordingly. If @AngelPray would confirm that this is the right kind of thing we might help him edit. If it’s *not*, then a discussion of how these answers are not what he wants might help him ask a fresh question (in the Sandbox first).

Comment: @JDługosz I think it would be best to put this thing though the sandbox: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions/4635#4635

Comment: While you work in the sandbox...I'm pretty sure a figure 8 would work. Similar to the mobius strip but it has the added bonus of being one of the symbols for infinity (when viewed perpendicular, as we would in the normal non magical dimension.) Both heaven and hell have both up and down forces but with different degrees of attraction/strength. Less nether, more aether in the top heaven. Less aether, more nether in the bottom hell level. Where they meet in the middle would be the mortal realm. This way nothing is ever created nor destroyed and everything has an equal and opposite reaction.

Answer (score 6):

## wrap-around dimension

A looping dimension where stuff that goes far enough in that direction comes in from the opposite, like the screen of PacMan or Asteroids.

### nonorientable

**But…** it has a twist like a Möbius strip.  The twist might be of the same kind as the dimension’s direction, which is most elegant, so things that go off the top come back from the bottom *with opposite chirality* (or handedness).  The same particle is aether or nether depending on its spin, just as neutrinos only feel the weak force if left-handed.

The twist can also be in a different kind of space, so it flips matter and anti matter, not just direction.  This could be a continuous gage transformation blah technobabble.  This [plot from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_strip#Geometry_and_topology) shows the idea with how the colors change gradually as well as the band being twisted.

[image: strip with colors changing]

See [Mr Ug and Wind: The Same Side of the Story](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WQ97c-rPUVc) on YouTube for a clever take on the subject.

### symmetry breaking

Forget the twist and consider a plain wrap-around dimension.

One way is just like the other, right?  Well, things *in* that space can break the symmetry.  Consider establishing an electric field in that direction.  One way will be positive and the other negative.

Because of this field positive particles will be falling in from one direction and negative particles from the other direction.  Tney both just loop around, passing the planet on each lap.

Substitute a novel field with a similar 2-way charge and your two kinds of particles bearing the respective charges.

Answer (score 2):

I recently watched [this series of videos on Primer Fields](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1UPORMPgqw&list=PL1lUiaQg0SKuojC4rYXmWB-Nven7P6j7M). The videos are slow, but he goes into detail about the shape and the magnetic properties. Sounds like it might be a good fit for your loop magic. Skip to 45min for this demonstration. It's a good analogy for how our physical plane could be held in place by two opposing energy fields:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, but I'm unsure how this answers my question. Could you provide a bit more detail if possible?

Comment: It is best to include the relevant information from a linked source. The link could become stale and the value of the answer is lost.

Comment: Reading another answer (Pac-Man) and re-reading your question, I may have misunderstood your description of a loop. Primer Fields (according to the video) are two bowl shapes with opposite magnetic charges. when they come together they have many interesting properties where the fields overlap and interact. In the pic above, the metal balls are held in place by the opposing magnetic fields. It fits some of your criteria, and the two opposing electrical fields loop as mirror energies. At a distance from the bowls the magnetic field does a full loop as you describe.

roughly, this shape: (8)

Comment: Yes, I think you might have... I'm interesting in having a topological shape that somehow permits a continuous flow in one direction and a continuous flow in the opposite direction to both eventually lead to a same point without ever intersecting with each other (save for that point).

Comment: This shape can do that. Any magnet can. Follow the ion trail from north pole to south. It leaves heading north and eventually curves around and arrives at the south pole of the magnet.

Comment: Yes, @wetcircuit, it was noted that the question is not clear.  But in your example, how is the field above and the field below giving rise to *different* magical stuff?

Answer (score 2):

Can we go crazy? Let's go crazy. I like to go crazy.

You can solve this using a parallel 4D dimensional plane interlocked with our 
3D universe.

Let's look to a misterious friend of ours, Gravity, for some references. I'll be using the layman terms that I use for my daughters.

Let's use a 2D universe and do some weird Unicode Art.

You have two orbs. Orb A and Orb B. They have some empty space between then.

A ●- - - - - - - - - - - - - ●B

Now, those orbs have mass, they would immediately interact with each other. Gravity would make each one of them pull the other closer.

This...

A ●►►►►►-◄◄◄◄◄●B

Will become this, given enough time:

. - - - - - - - - A●●B - - - - - - - - - -.

However, Gravity doesn't disappear. The forces are still pulling those two together, and thus you still have the same fields "flowing". They're just centered now.

►►►►►A●●B◄◄◄◄◄

So, for observer, you have a "inwards only" force going on, here, directed to the "center" of our system. In our 2D universe, now you have "two forces" - one pulling left, the other one pulling right. If you swap this around to create some sort of anti-gravity for this 2D universe...

◄◄◄◄◄A●●B►►►►►

AND make it so that you only have the one "orb", at the center....

◄◄◄◄◄ ● ►►►►►

You have a single field "pointing" outwards from the center of your universe.

Now, if we suppose that you have an otherwise regular universe like ours, but:

- This universe has something special at its center;
- This special thing exists on a different plane than the ones we can access on our 3 dimensions - being probably 4D;
- This special thing creates a field that is analogous to gravity, but doesn't interact with anything that matters to humans and flows in the opposite direction, going *outwards* from the center;

*THEN*:

You have your thing.

Comment: Yes, but if you were to place a "particle" of say nether on one of these fields wouldn't it just continue being pushed away from the orb forever without ever "looping back"?

Comment: @AngelPray Hm. If you need for it to "loop back" you should use a 5D universe, then, using the extra dimension to make the trip back. I'll illustrate once I get home!

Comment: Minor nitpick: it's not ASCII art if it contains Unicode characters.

Comment: @AidanF.Pierce my thought exactly! So what’s the proper term, especially when using characters designed for that express purpose?

Comment: «something special at its center» I'm thinking the people’s *planet* defines a center for this purpose, without being an absolute center.  However you still have to explain why symmetry is broken: why the field above is different from the field below?

Comment: @AidanF.Pierce Solved ;P